# unshift vs assigning the values with loop vs manually assigning values by hand. Which one is faster?

Tags: javascript, arrays, insert

For javascript which one is faster?

```
a.unshift("new first value");
```

vs

```
for(i=a.length; i>0; i--) a[i] = a[i-1];
a[0] = "new first value";
```

vs

```
a[5] = a[4];
a[4] = a[3];
a[3] = a[2];
a[2] = a[1];
a[1] = a[0];
a[0] = "new first value";
```

Well, of course, assigning values by hand is unpractical.
But there would be cases that your array has very few items that you can assign it with your hand and it's in a loop that would repeat it millions of times.
So I just included it.

Then the main question is:

1. Is there any performance difference between first two cases?
2. And can third one be faster than both of them

Comment: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: @VLAZ Aside from being unnecessary rude comment, I'll just answer to your article's questions.
1. Why are you even asking me?
Because there are many people that has more knowledge than me duh. I needed info and i'm asking the info. Why are you asking that why am i asking the question. 
2. Do you really need to answer that question? - Yes.
3. Is that really the bottleneck? - Can be. I'll be deciding that after I got information.
4. Is the difference relevant? - Yes

Comment: Quick check:
https://shorturl.at/itPQ9 - `unshift` is 50 times faster in my browser

Comment: @VLAZ 5. What is this “faster” you speak of? - Performing faster by time. I know optimizing one thing might lead to deoptimize another thing. But should i use that optimization or not is up to me decide. Again I need info so I can decide.
6. Are you looking at the big picture? - Yes. But that's not relevant here. I'm here for info. Not some rants.

Comment: *"Is there any performance difference between first two cases?/And can third one be faster than both of them when"* Benchmark them and tell us

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems the manual assignment is good with a small number of items only, then `unshift` takes the place.

```
` Chrome/123
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>                 n=5       |       n=50        |      n=500       |      n=5000     
unshift      2.02x x10m 704 |  1.00x   x1m   96 |  1.00x   x1m 521 |  1.00x x100k 426
splice       2.03x x10m 706 |  1.38x   x1m  132 |  1.18x   x1m 614 |  1.24x x100k 529
loop         1.16x x10m 404 |  3.05x   x1m  293 |  5.34x x100k 278 |  2.63x  x10k 112
manual       1.00x x10m 348 |  1.13x  x10m 1085 |  1.52x   x1m 794 | 11.17x  x10k 476
copyWithin   6.87x  x1m 239 | 15.21x x100k  146 | 24.95x  x10k 130 | 30.75x   x1k 131
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

In Firefox `splice` is the fastest:

```
` Firefox/124
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>                 n=5       |     n=50      |      n=500      |     n=5000    
splice       1.71x x10m 580 | 1.30x x1m 161 | 1.03x x100k 251 | 1.00x x10k 208
unshift      1.42x x10m 482 | 1.15x x1m 143 | 1.00x x100k 244 | 1.30x x10k 271
copyWithin   1.43x x10m 487 | 1.86x x1m 231 | 1.64x x100k 401 | 1.40x x10k 291
loop         1.67x x10m 568 | 3.57x x1m 443 | 2.30x x100k 562 | 2.50x x10k 521
manual       1.00x x10m 340 | 1.00x x1m 124 | 1.68x x100k 410 | 3.18x x10k 661
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
let $length = 5;
let b = Array.from({length:$length}, (_,i) => i+1);

// @benchmark manual
const genAssign = length => new Function('a', Array.from({length}, (_, i) => `a[${length - i}] = a[${length - i - 1}]`).join(';'))

const assign = genAssign($length);
// @run
a = b.slice();
assign(a);
a[0] = "new first value";

// @benchmark loop
a = b.slice();
for(i=a.length; i>0; i--) a[i] = a[i-1];
a[0] = "new first value";

// @benchmark unshift
a = b.slice();
a.unshift("new first value");

// @benchmark splice
a = b.slice();
a.splice(0, 0, "new first value");

// @benchmark copyWithin
a = b.slice();
a.length++;
a.copyWithin(1, 0, a.length);
a[0] = "new first value";


/*@skip*/ fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js').then(r => r.text().then(eval));
```

Comment: _"The manual seems a clear winner."_ `splice()` is fastest on Chromium 125. "manual" is fastest on Firefox 126.

Comment: @guest271314 for me it's the same on chrome 125, maybe cpu difference, i have i-12600k

Comment: Could be. I would run the same code in `deno`, `bun`, `node`, `tjs,`, `qjs` for more comprehensive test result.

Comment: You seem to have edited "manual assigning" to "assigning index value to i variable". Maybe that can be taken as its own different way to assign values instead of actually being manually writing.

Comment: @BallGNM i'm generating js "manual" assignment code like trincot suggested. after benchmarking the result is almost the same as with true manual code so it's valid to some degree. that way we can generate "manual" code for different array size which is interesting to benchmark

Comment: Ok. But the point of manually assigning is to avoid all those length - i - 1 calculations. And if it loops million times, there will be million more calculations, since it has 2 operands, there will 2 million more calculations actually. So I'd say it's not the same as true manual.

Comment: @BallGNM length - i - 1 are interpolated and calculated ahead, a pure `a[5] = a[4]` is executed inside the generated function

Comment: @BallGNM it was hard to setup the benchmark, i forgot to parameterize the manual assignment generation. so `unshift` is a winner

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev For that, I'd still say manual is winner. Because I'd never use manual assignment for array that has more than 5 or 6 items. 50 is too much items to manually set. Let alone 500 or 5000.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function dynamically that makes all the individual assignments, using the `Function` constructor.

The bigger the array, the more dramatic the difference in running time. Here is a script that creates an array with one million entries, and the dynamic function with as many assignments (+ 1). It then calls the function once and also `unshift`

```js
// Test with an array with a million values
const a = [...Array(1e6).keys()];
const b = [...Array(1e6).keys()];
// Dynamically create a function that makes all assignments as individual JS statements
const f1 = new Function("a", "value", a.map((_, i) => 
    `a[${i+1}]=a[${i}];`
).reverse().join("\n") + "\na[0]=value;");
// ...and the alternative that uses the native unshift method
function f2(a, value) { a.unshift(value); }

function timeit(f, a) {
  const start = performance.now();
  f(a, "x");
  console.log(performance.now() - start);
}

timeit(f1, a);
timeit(f2, b);
// repeat with the same arrays:
a.shift(); b.shift();
timeit(f1, a);
timeit(f2, b);
// Verify the results are identical
console.log(JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b) ? "same" : "different");
```

Clearly `unshift` wins once the array size becomes significant. This should not come as a surprise as once the JS call of `unshift` is made, no more JS code is concerned, and the actual shifting can rely on compiled C code.

Answer (score -1):

It depends but in general, directly assigning values by hand tends to be faster than using methods like unshift() or looping to assign values to an array. This is because direct assignment involves fewer operations and less overhead compared to shifting existing elements or iterating over the array.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking that too. For example for FOR loop assigning values to i variable and checking if that variable has reached the end each can be considered one operation. So it can be slower than assigning it manually.
But is for loop faster than unshift? Of course I could check with dummy data. But what I want is how it works behind the curtain. So there must always be someone who knows the stuff.

Comment: Just realise that the bigger the array is, the more gain you'll get from calling `unshift`. Although the accepted answer says that "manual" assignments are the clear winner, I wouldn't call that clear at all. The tables turn quickly. Every assignment in JS *is an overhead* that `unshift` doesn't have. So you have the tradeoff between one overhead (of calling the function) against several smaller overheads (for each manual assignment).

Comment: @trincot Yeah, I agree on bigger arrays. But there might be some arrays with only 4, 5 members that I could just assign it manually in the code instead of using unshift, for the speed purpose.

Comment: Sure, as I said: there is a tradoff, and thus a tipping point. At some point `unshift` will win the race. Your question also spoke of "millions"...

Comment: @trincot Well, I said millions of loops. Not arrays with millions of items. Anyway thanks for helping. All new answers gave me something I didn't know.